# SSIS Script Task Excel Instance Not Closing

Tags: excel, vb.net, ssis

So I have a Script Task in SSIS which opens, refreshes, closes, and saves an Excel file.  It does this using Visual Basic.  It works perfectly and does exactly what I want it to do.  However, I can not get the Excel instance itself to close and I've been trying to figure out why for hours.  Here's the current code:

```
Public Sub Main()

    'On Error GoTo Quit

    Dim excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

    excel.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("FilePath")

    wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(2, 18).Value = "thru " & IIf((Month(DateAdd("D", -1, Today)) < 10), "0" & Month(DateAdd("D", -1, Today)), Month(DateAdd("D", -1, Today))) & "/" & Format(Convert.ToDateTime(DateAdd("D", -1, Today)), "dd") & "/" & Format(Convert.ToDateTime(DateAdd("D", -1, Today)), "yyyy")

    wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh()
    wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh()
    wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh()
    wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh()
    wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh()
    wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh()

    'Choose arrow based on criteria
    If wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(13, 16).Value > wb.Sheets("Summary").Cells(13, 14).Value Then
        wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Shapes("Shape").Copy()
        wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(12, 13).Select()
        wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Paste()
    Else
        wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Shapes("Shape").Copy()
        wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(12, 13).Select()
        wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Paste()
    End If

    wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Shapes("Shape").Delete()
    wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Shapes("Shape").Delete()

    wb.Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(2, 2).Select()

    wb.SaveAs("FilePath")

    wb.Close()
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb)

    excel.DisplayAlerts = True
    excel.Quit()
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel)

    'wb = Nothing
    'excel = Nothing

    'GC.Collect()

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

    'Quit:   excel.Quit()

End Sub
```

Can anyone figure out why this would not close the instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're leaking a ton of COM objects, that's why.

```
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("path")
```

This leaks the `Workbooks` collection object.

```
wb.Sheets("Summary").Cells(2, 18).Value = something
```

This leaks the `Sheets` collection object, the `Worksheet` object retrieved from it, and the `Range` object obtained from that `Cells` call.

```
wb.Sheets("Summary").Shapes("Down Arrow 3").Copy()
```

Again, leaking the `Sheets` collection, the retrieved `Worksheet` instance, the `Shapes` collection, and the retrieved `Shape` object.

This is interop between COM and .NET: you're not in VBA-land here, you're not in-process either.

You can't chain member calls like this. You need to hold a reference to every COM object you access, and properly release it.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb)
```

That's the workbook, ...but then there are now runtime callable wrappers (RCWs) disconnected from their underlying COM object, lingering in managed memory - *that* is what's keeping the EXCEL.EXE process alive: these COM objects aren't accessible anymore, and there's nothing to release them.

Split the chained member calls.

```
Dim wbSheets As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheets = wb.Sheets
Dim summarySheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet =wbSheets("Summary")
'...
```

Then release these as well:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbSheets)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(summarySheet)
'...
```

For *all of them*. Then the process should exit cleanly.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu.  Wow, I had no idea SSIS used .NET for the Script Task.  I thought it used VBA which I was somewhat used to.  This is way over my head.  I think I'll just use the Execute Process Task instead to automate my jobs since the Access files are already built.

Comment: @Anonymous eh, you're almost there. Just need to extract a bunch of local variables and release them as soon as you're done with them, and all will be fine - the problem is the chained member calls, something you just don't need to care about in VBA because you're in-process. Note that out-of-process VBA code can very well leak implicit objects in the very same identical way, e.g. if you automate Word from an Excel VBA project; resulting in a ghost WINWORD.EXE process that's left behind even after Excel is closed.

Comment: Hey Mathieu, do you know how I could split the following chained member call? Dim Wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open("FilePath") I think this is the only variable keeping me from fully being able to drop all the COM objects.  I've split everything else out and this is the only one where I'm not following the "one dot good, two dots bad" rule.

Comment: @Anonymous that's still leaking the `Workbooks` collection, which is an object of type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks`. Declare some `books` variable and set it to `excel.Workbooks`, then get the book from `books.Open("filepath")`. Note, VB.NET isn't case-sensitive; I woud avoid naming the `Excel.Application` variable `Excel`, since it seems to clash with a namespace; `app` should be perfectly safe.

Comment: Thanks so much Mathieu.  I finally managed to strip it but I still have an Excel instance running in the background, although I did notice it's smaller in size now so I think I'm just missing an object somewhere.  EDIT:  Whoops, spoke too soon.  Looks like it's the same size, so I'll have to do some digging.

Comment: Mathieu, I just wanted to thank you for your help.  I owe you a debt of gratitude.  I finally managed to get the entire thing to run without leaking any COM objects, although it was a bear to do so since this was my first time.  We're in the process of moving away from Access and into SSIS, and this breaks the initial barrier.  Thanks again so much for your help and I hope to see you around :)